# Unexpected file found in package directory: F:\Mine\SalesForce\Salesforce CLI\HelloWorldLightningWebComponent\force-app\main\default\engine.d.ts

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

This error
 Unexpected file found in package directory: F:\Mine\SalesForce\Salesforce CLI\HelloWorldLightningWebComponent\force-app\main\default\engine.d.ts.

shown up when I'm trying to run command SFDX: Push Source to Default Scratch Org in lightning web component

[image]

Comment: That file should not be there. What are you trying to do with the file?

Comment: I've edited the question you can check the attached pic this file was updated automatically when I tried to create a component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you didn't make/copy those files, most likely there was a bug with one of the extensions when you installed/upgraded it. You might try checking for new updates to the extensions and the CLI itself.

Don't worry about it, you can safely delete any `*.d.ts` files that you find in your main paths (e.g. `force-app`). Do not tamper with the files found in `.sfdx/typings/lwc`, however, as they are necessary for proper LWC auto-completion.